Snippet funciona no modo de edição, mas não quando salva
Sugeri uma edição na resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/595169/163584, mas no modo de edição o snippet funciona, mas quando salva, ele deixa de funcionar, achei que o problema fosse o código comentado no início do snippet, mas ao removê-lo, o problema persiste.

É intencional, publicações com muitos downvotes terão o snippet desabilitado.

@Syzoth, ah beleza, obrigado pela resposta.
